# How do i turn off django's plural notation in the admin page

Tags: python, django

I have some tables that are presented as inlines of another class. I have altered the default title of these inline representations by adding an inner class to the respective tables.

`class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Binnengekomen punten'`

I have only the verbose_name defined but it still adds an s to all the names. So 'Binnengekomen punten' is displayed as 'Binnengekomen puntens'
What i could do is define the plural of verbose_name `verbose_name_plural` the same as verbose_name. But is there a way to simply turn off the plural notation? I'd love to know thank you.

Answer (score 2):

according to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.verbose_name) there isn't method to turn off plural notation.

If `verbose_name_plural` isn't given Django uses `verbose_name + 's'`

Comment: this is a nice simple solution to the original question, I think this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Adding a suffix is hardcoded, we can see this in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/db/models/options.py#L189):

> ```
>             if self.verbose_name_plural is None:
>                 self.verbose_name_plural = format_lazy('{}s', self.verbose_name)
> ```

It does not make much sense to write the `verbose_name` as `'binnengekomen punten'` (incoming points), since that is *plural* and a `verbose_name` is supposed to be *singular*. You can however make a decorator that for example automatically defines the plural by adding `'en'` to the `verbose_name`, like:

```
def add_plural(cls, suffix='en'):
    if not hasattr(cls, 'verbose_name_plural'):
        try:
            cls.verbose_name_plural = cls.verbose_name + suffix
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    return cls
```

We can then use the decorator like:

```
class IncomingPoint(models.Model):
    # ...
    @add_plural
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Binnengekomen punt'
```

**EDIT**: You can turn of capitalization, by wrapping the items in a subclass of string, as is shown is in this [ticket #18129](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18129):

```
class NoCap(str):
    def upper(self):
        return self
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__class__(super().__getitem__(key))
```

We can then wrap the `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` into this:

```
def case_invariant_meta(cls, suffix='en'):
    try:
        cls.verbose_name = NoCap(cls.verbose_name)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        cls.verbose_name_plural = NoCap(cls.verbose_name_plural)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return cls
```

We can then annotate the `Meta` class:

```
class IncomingPoint(models.Model):
    # ...
    @case_invariant_meta
    @add_plural
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Binnengekomen punt'
```

Comment: I also noticed django capitalizes all table names on the admin page. Any chance this behaviour can be switched off?

Answer (score 1):

I’m sure that it’s *possible*, but can guarantee you that it would not be worth the effort. Just set the `verbose_plural_name`.

Comment: so there is no easy way to turn it off then?

Comment: You'd literally have to edit the source code for the `admin` app. So no.